# Add Object to list on initialization

Tags: swift, object, struct

is there any way to add an object to a list when creating it with Swift? I think you can do this with Java by doing `.add(this)` but I'm not sure on how to do it in Swift. This is the code I have right now. Doing the append doesn't seem to work as the list stays empty.

```
public struct Candle {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let burning: Bool
    let type: CandleType

    var differentCandles: [Candle] = []

    init(name: String, burning: Bool, candleType: CandleType) {
        self.name = name
        self.burning = burning
        self.type = candleType
        self.id = differentCandles.count + 1
        differentCandles.append(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong but this results into [retaining cycles](http://www.thomashanning.com/retain-cycles-weak-unowned-swift/). Why not just create the array outside of your model instead? This way you'll actually end up having a single container to store all of your objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try following to save appended data,

```
public struct Candle {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
  let burning: Bool
  let type: CandleType

  static var differentCandles: [Candle] = []

  init(name: String, burning: Bool, candleType: CandleType) {
      self.name = name
      self.burning = burning
      self.type = candleType
      self.id = Candle.differentCandles.count + 1
      Candle.differentCandles.append(self)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `.append(item)` is the good way to add an item to an array but in your case you're creating a retain cycle that will leak your application.

Your var `differentCandles` should be save somewhere else, or be static.